# API client design, should I check the parameters?

Tags: python, api, rest

I want to create a Python API wrapper for a RESTful API service, and I was thinking of how am I going to design it.

Example URL request:

```
https://www.api.com/collection/resource.json?userid=id&password=pass&command=value
```

I'm going to make every collection a module and the resources as functions in these modules, for example here's how I'm going to use the api:

```
from apiname import collection

# params is a dict of the parameters sent to this resource
params = {
    'userid': '123456',
    'password': 'pass',
    'command': 'value'
}

collection.resource(params)
```

My main question is about the `params` dict passed to the resource, should I check the parameters passed for the resource:

- check if required parameters are passed (maybe raise an exception if not passed)
- check for their types (str, list, int, bool)

or should I keep it simple and make the function send anything passed to it to the resource ?

If I should check the parameters, what is the recommended way to do it, I thought of keeping all the default parameters stored for each resource and then I check all the passed parameters with this default dict, for example:

```
# this is the dict holding the info about all the parameters
defaults = {}

defaults['userid'] = {'type': str, 'required': True, 'default': None}
defaults['password'] = {'type': str, 'required': True, 'default': None}
defaults['command'] = {'type': list, 'required': False, 'default': 'some-value'}
```

So what path should follow ?

Comment: Will it enhance the client developer's experience/make it easier for the client to develop using your API by providing error checking?

Comment: @dm03514 yes it will, but any recommendations or examples are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the parameters on the client side, you'll create a strong coupling between the current client and server implementations. If the server changes whatever parameters or values it accepts for some resource, it may break the client and demand changes. This is really undesirable in REST. Even if the API is really RESTful, your client won't be, and you won't leverage on the benefits of the architecture.

You shouldn't check the parameters on the client side. Rather than that, you should treat carefully the errors returned by the server. Ideally, they should detail if one or more parameters are inadequate or missing.